# localhost blocked on Chrome with "Privacy Error"

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

Google Chrome is blocking `localhost`.

I'm using `XAMPP` with `Apache localhost`, ports `80` and `443`. Google Chrome is up to date.

I'm getting the following error:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Try this:

In Chrome, put in chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost in the address bar.

Enable the option that says "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost".

Restart Chrome, and it should allow the site.

Comment: Would there be any downsides to this? Any actual issues with allowing insecure from localhost?

Comment: I can't see why, seeing as localhost is just your local machine.

Comment: Not working for me on Chrome 62.0.3202.94, even if the flag is there it seems to not have any effect.

Comment: Worked for me after changing hostnames from *.dev to *.local. Tested on Apache Windows 10.

Comment: @TomShaw Can confirm, I changed my example.dev to example.io and it started to work

Comment: This solution didn't work for me but the solution below about not using .dev worked! FYI. Try both.

Comment: I cannot find option "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost" on Chrome 119.0.6045.160

Answer (score 22):

From Chrome version 63, it will redirect all .dev extension to domain https
So try another extension to another, ex .test, .local...
You can refer here: https://docs.serverpress.com/article/234-your-connection-is-not-private-google-chrome

Comment: This *exactly* solved my problem. Was using .dev domain, changed that to .git and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: This was my issue as well, using the .dev domain, changed it to .local and worked fine

Answer (score 18):

Try typing in your are blocked page **thisisunsafe**. Simple type this word on keyboard. I found solution from this https://medium.com/@dblazeski/chrome-bypass-net-err-cert-invalid-for-development-daefae43eb12

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me just by changing " .dev" to ".local"
I'm using windows 10

Answer (score 3):

**your connection is not private** for *virtual host* in **XAMPP**

I've faced the same problem, Now It has been solved it.

don't use '.dev' for your local domains - the new chrome (version 63) redirects all .dev -Domains to 'https://name.dev'

Try to rename your local domains to something like '.test' and 'phpmyadmin.test' or whatever

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Kyle Erickson's answer didn't work for me.
I changed the host name and it was ok. You can also use the ip directly.

Answer (score 0):

**How to enable chrome**: //flags/#allow-insecure-localhost on chrome? you might want to jump over to the beta branch of your browser. That, however, isn’t really necessary as there is indeed another way to enable the allow-insecure-localhost flag on Chrome. The steps for this have been given below:

1. Launch ‘chrome://flags’ from address bar
2. Set "Temporarily unexpire M118 flags." and "Temporarily unexpire M117 flags." to Enabled
   [image]
3. Restart Chrome
4. Launch ‘chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost’
5. It will be visible now, so simply enable it
6. Restart Chrome again

**Note**-: This would be applicable for Chrome higher version 117,118 and 119 and more.

Answer (score -7):

Reset your browser.Remove cache and cookies from your browser.Try now your website. It should work.
Still doesn't work let us know in comments below.

Comment: should be in comment.