# chrome blocked localhost with error your connection is not private

Tags: mysql, google-chrome, phpmyadmin, localhost

Suddenly google chrome has blocked localhost. I am not able to use phpmyadmin and my project. It's supporting remaining sites perfectly. Whenever I run phpmyadmin or project it shows an error as follows:

> Your connection is not private
>    "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"

I tried a lot of things to solve it but none of suggestions are working. Anybody please help.

Comment: This?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531347/localhost-blocked-on-chrome-with-privacy-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [localhost blocked on Chrome with "Privacy Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531347/localhost-blocked-on-chrome-with-privacy-error)

Comment: @CC I've tried that but not working.

Comment: @CC I've tried that but not working.

Answer (score 3):

Just type the phrase "thisisunsafe" and hit enter you will instantly bypass that warning screen. This seriously works It blew my mind

Answer (score 0):

I think you use local domain like `yourDomainName.dev`
Just don't use `.dev` for your local domains. 
If happened because new version Chrome always redirect to `https`

Just rename `yourDomainName.dev` something like `yourDomainName.local` or `yourDomainName.loc`.

Comment: Or `*.localhost`, which will not confuse the browser since it will understand that you're working on localhost.