# laravel, privacy error while renaming server name

Tags: laravel

I created a laravel app named `lsapp` , I can access laravel landing page `http://localhost/lsapp/public/` .

To hide public folder, I decided to route through `lsapp.dev/`. But when I try to load in chrome , it shows privacy error.

Following changes were made,

in system32/drivers/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 lsapp.dev
```

in httpd.vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/programs/php/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
   
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/programs/php/htdocs/htdocs/public"
    ServerName lsapp.dev

</VirtualHost>
```

[image: error]

Comment: Seems like chrome is just blocking not secured domain. Try this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531347/localhost-blocked-on-chrome-with-privacy-error

Comment: `E:/programs/php/htdocs/htdocs/public` ?? Two `htdocs`? Also, don't use your localhost's DocumentRoot for other projects. Use something like `E:/programs/php/lsapp/public`

Comment: A simpler solution is to use the domain `lsapp.test`